# " charachter changing for JSON

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have drugnames like `drugnameexmp "20 tbl"`

The ' " ' charachter makes trouble for creating a NSString that it is for JSON.

```
{\"drugname\":\"%@\",drugname}
```

How can I change '"' charachter for it?The below code is what I tried.

```
[drug setValue:[[drug objectForKey:@"drug_name"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""] forKey:@"drug_name"];
```

Thank you.

**Edited:**

It acts like this:

```
{
"drugname":"drugnameexmp "20 tbl",
"id":123

}
```

"drugnameexmp "20 tbl" looks like this: `"drugnameexmp "` + `20 tbl"`
' " ' parses the NSString. I want `" drugnameexmp '20 tbl' "`.

```
NSString *s=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"drugname\":\"%@\",\"id\":%d,drugname,id} "];
 NSData *myPostData = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableData *myMutablePostData = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithData:myPostData];

    [request setPostBody:myMutablePostData];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startSynchronous];
```

Comment: This is for incoming JSON, or for creating JSON? What code are you using to do that?

Comment: Please be clear, what you are getting and what you want?

Comment: I add some more explanation to my question.@Wain it is for creation JSON.

Comment: @user3309441, calm down, and please try to reword your problem much more clear, because that is highly ambiguous currently.

Comment: It is clear. Sorry about it but how can I be more clear. I gave examples. It is "charachter seperates a NSString problem." :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier just to use a JSON serializer.

```
NSDictionary *JSON = @{ @"drugname" : drugname, @"id" : ID };
NSData *myPostData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSON options:0 error:NULL];
```

Comment: You saved my day!! Thank you so much! I couldn't think this way.